# How to set UICollectionViewCell height to 90% of the View (Screen) height?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to set the UICollectionViewCell height as 90% of the screen size. So the cell size would look good when using different devices.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to set the cell height programmatically. All cell should look the same size, so there's no need to consider the content, I only want the cell height to be 90% of the screen.

Here is what it looks like in iphone 6 screen:
[image]

However, when switching to a smaller device it looks like this:
[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you using the flow layout?

Comment: did you set constrains to your `imageView`& `label` or `textView` etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your `UICollectionView`'s flow layout tile size programmatically. There are a couple of different places you could cause this, I would start with `viewWillAppear` (in your ViewController class) for starters:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    if let layout = self.schedulesView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        var cellSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size // start with the full screen size
        cellSize.height *= 0.9 // adjust the height by 90%
        layout.itemSize = cellSize // set the layouts item size
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to implement it but the result is different than I expected. The red 'loading' area on the top is pulled up and out of the collection view. Height is also not changing.

Comment: I was able to resize the height of the collectionViewCell with your method. However, the items inside the cell won't resize accordingly. Do I have to manually resize them?

Comment: It depends on how you laid them out in the first place. If you used constraint based layout, you shouldn't have to. If you just drug things around on the screen and set explicit pixel values, then yes. And then there's the whole legacy autoresizing behaviors, but I'm not an authority on those. I just use constraints all the way down.

Comment: Hi Travis, thanks for replying. I did drag things into the cell. However, inside the cell, there's a label that has 4 constraints tied to the cell, and I've also set the label's width and height to be equal to the cell's. This label won't resize accordingly.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the cell that's too wide? In the example I gave I put the cell width nominally at the screen width. But that's just a starting point. Experiment with the width (e.g. add 'cellSize.width = 100') and see if that affects anything.

Comment: Hey Travis, thanks for replying. I was able to add more width and height to the collection view cell when changing to a bigger screen. However, I still cannot figure out how to resize the items inside the screen to change size accordingly. This is really weird. I have also tried to use 'sizeForItemAtIndexPath' but the result is the same.

Comment: Might be a second question. I saw your answer below, I've never had to do that, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Can you dumb that behavior down to a simple bit of code that reproduces the problem and you can share in a second question? That would help quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `collectionView` `itemSize` by using `collectionViewFlowLayout` according to `device size`. Try below method..

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
   // All the values are changable according to your needs.
    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 25, left: 3, bottom: 3, right: 3)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 50
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 50
    return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width - 50, height:self.collectionView.frame.height - 100)
}
```

**Note:** From the above code you will get box type `collectionView itemSize` that covers the view accordingly to device size.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the help. I tried to implement your methods. It did add more size to the collectionViewCell. However, all the items inside the cell won't resize. As shown in the image, the bottom textView's height won't grow. I have set textView's width and height to the Cell's on a certain ratio. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured what the problem is with contents inside UICollectionViewCell not updating their size.

Just need to as this to the subclass of UICollectionViewCell

```
override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
      contentView.frame = bounds
    }
}
```